# Extends Java Applet Making Everything Invisible - CLOSED

Tags: java, applet

I have a working Java Application that is randomizing a string and every other time when you click the button it will show the randomized text. So when someone clicks the button it will tell them what position in the game they are, then brings them to a blank screen waiting for the next player to click, and etc. It works perfectly but when I copy the code to a new file and type:

```
extends JApplet
```

The window in eclipse is just blank, nothing in it. I get no errors in the console though when running this. My basic aim is to make this application a java applet so I can post it online and hopefully open it on other devices without download, like an iPhone.

Code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JApplet{

private static JFrame window = new JFrame();

private static JPanel one = new JPanel();
private static JPanel two = new JPanel();

//1-4 Players
private static JLabel job1 = new JLabel();
private static JLabel job2 = new JLabel();
private static JLabel job3 = new JLabel();
private static JLabel job4 = new JLabel();
private static JLabel jobprint = new JLabel();

private static JButton next = new JButton("Click To Find Your Position");

private static int countertwo = 0;
private static int counter = 0;


public static void shuffleArray(String[] a) {
int n = a.length;
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  int change = i + random.nextInt(n - i);
  swap(a, i, change);
}
}

private static void swap(String[] a, int i, int change) {
String helper = a[i];
a[i] = a[change];
a[change] = helper;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] a = new String[] { "Murderer", "Judge", "Innocent", "Innocent"};
shuffleArray(a);

next.setVisible(true);
job1.setVisible(false);
job2.setVisible(false);
job3.setVisible(false);
job4.setVisible(false);



for (String i : a) {
  System.out.println(i);
  counter++;
  if(counter == 1){
     job1.setText(i); 
  }
  if(counter == 2){
      job2.setText(i);
  }
  if(counter == 3){
      job3.setText(i);
  }
  if(counter == 4){
      job4.setText(i);
  }
}

next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(countertwo == 0){
            jobprint.setVisible(true);
            jobprint.setText(job1.getText());
            next.setText("Click Again");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 1){
            jobprint.setText("");
            next.setText("Click To Find Your Position");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 2){
            jobprint.setText(job2.getText());
            next.setText("Click Again");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 3){
            jobprint.setText("");
            next.setText("Click To Find Your Position");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 4){
            jobprint.setText(job3.getText());
            next.setText("Click Again");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 5){
            jobprint.setText("");
            next.setText("Click To Find Your Position");
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 6){
            jobprint.setText(job4.getText());
            countertwo++;
        }else if(countertwo == 7){
            jobprint.setText("Finished - Application by Fletcher Henneman");
            next.setVisible(false);
        }
     }
    });


window.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
window.setSize(500,400);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setResizable(false);

window.add(one);
window.add(two);

one.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));
two.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));

one.add(jobprint);

two.add(next);


window.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: Applets do not have a main() method, they have an init() method.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm

Comment: I changed main to init, nothing it changing.

Comment: Applets are dead technology. You are not going to be able to run it on standard mobile browser for Apple or Android phones and none of them have Java plugin support. I'd say don't bother.

Comment: http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/

Comment: All of the Java to C++ converters I have tried, have failed so this is basically a last resort for me.

Comment: Is there any way to run this on an iPhone?